# Creating a page that detects multiple usernames when they login.PHP

Tags: php, file-io, increment

I want to increment `$userCount` by 1 every time $data and `$fileLineArr2[0]` have the same value. Could someone explain why `$userCount` remains `0`? I'm a programming student, so please keep help in a way that is understandable to someone with only intermediate experience.

```
if(!empty($_GET["user"]) && !empty($_GET["pass"]) && !empty($_GET["fname"]) && !empty($_GET["lname"])){

    $handle = fopen($accountInfo, 'a') or die('Cannot open file: '.$accountInfo);
    $data = $_GET["user"]."; ";
    $data = strtoupper($data);
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    $data2 = $_GET["pass"]."; ";
    fwrite($handle, $data2);
    $data3 = $_GET["fname"]."; ";
    fwrite($handle, $data3);
    $data4 = $_GET["lname"].";\n";
    fwrite($handle, $data4);
    fclose($handle);

    $reading2 = fopen($accountInfo, 'r') or die('Cannot open file: '.$accountInfo);

    echo "$userCount";

    while(!feof($reading2)){
            $fileLines2 = fgets($reading2);
            $fileLineArr2 = (explode("; ", $fileLines2));
            //print_r($fileLineArr2);
            **if($fileLineArr2[0] == $data)
            {
                $userCount++;
            }**
            echo "$fileLineArr2[0] ";
            echo " $data". "\n";
            echo "$userCount";
        }


    fclose($reading2);
    if($userCount > 1)
    {
        $validSignUp = false;
        ?>
        <font color='red'>Username already taken!</font>
        <?php
    }
    elseif($userCount == 0)
    {
        ;
    }
    else
    {
        $validLogin = true;
        $validSignUp = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `**` surrounding the if statement?

Comment: That's the point of emphasis in my code. I don't compile it with the asterisks

Comment: Use a comment next time. People may point that out as an error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading from a file, there is an invisible new line character at the end of the string. You will want to remove that and then compare against the `$data`.

To remove the new line character, you can do something like

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Where `$string` is the line from the file.

**EDIT**

Based on a discussion in the comments section, this is not what you want.

What you will want to do is the following:

```
$line = explode('; ', $lineData);
```

Where `$lineData` is the information being read from the file.

This will give you an array of all the elements that were listed on the line. We know that the username is listed in the first position, IE `$line[0]`. So we compare our data with that.

```
if ($line[0] == $data) {
    $userCount++;
}
```

Where `$data` is the information we are comparing against.

Comment: Thank you for the information about the new line character at the end of a string. However, this didn't fix my issue with incrementing the $userCount variable. Here is the output:

Comment: Are you certain there are duplicates?

Comment: KTRIBBLE TYTRIB; 0USER2 TYTRIB; 0DABEARS TYTRIB; 0TYTRIB TYTRIB; 0JB TYTRIB; 0TYTRIB TYTRIB; 0TYTRIB TYTRIB; 0 TYTRIB; 0                       As you can see, there are two TYTRIB usernames, however the $userCount variable doesn't increment.

Comment: this will never work because you have more than just the username on the line. You are either going to have to `explode()` on a space and compare each segment of the returned array, or use a regular expression. Is the `;` supposed to represent a line ending, or is that actually in the text file?

Comment: Here is the text file:

Comment: KTRIBBLE; pass; K**; T****e;
USER2; pass2; user; two;
DABEARS; dabears; Mike; Ditka;
TYTRIB; pass3; Tye; Tribbet;
JB; pass4; jb; hunt;  These are all on separate lines and are generated when a user signs up.

Comment: Does the `;` represent a new line in this case, or is that all on one line?

Comment: The format is [username]; [password]; [FirstName]; [LastName]; <newline>.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer. That should be what you are looking for.

Comment: That solution was in my code already though. The username is [0], password is [1], and so on.

Comment: The problem is here --> if($fileLineArr2[0] == $data)
            {
                $userCount++;
            } --> for some reasone, $fileLineArr2[0] == $data is always false.

Comment: It's been fixed. Here is the solution:

Comment: $reading2 = fopen($accountInfo, 'r') or die('Cannot open file: '.$accountInfo);
  
  
  if(strpos(file_get_contents("assignment11-account-info.txt"),$user) !== false){
   while(!feof($reading2)){
    $fileLines = fgets($reading2);
    $fileLineArr = (explode("; ", $fileLines));
     if($fileLineArr[0] == $user)
     {
      $userExists = true;
     }    
    
   }
  }// $user is a new variable I created to store $_GET["user"]